# Google-Sheets: How to select all output cells after applying formula in 1-Step

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to keep output values and remove formula after applying it.
In order to do so, currently I have to steps:

1. Manually select all output cells(CTRL + Shift + down key) .
2. Copy-Paste all output cells as values.

Is there more faster way to do so ?

Comment: No. This is faster way you already have.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this method is included in your expected direct, I proposed an answer using Google Apps Script, please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure whether this method is included in your expected direct, for example, how about using Google Apps Script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. And, please reopen Google Spreadsheet. By this, the custom menu of "sample" is created.

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("sample")
    .addItem("selected cells", "sample1")
    .addItem("all data cells", "sample2")
    .addToUi();
}

function sample1() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true });
}

function sample2() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

- When you test "selected cells" is run from the custom menu, please select the cells you want to use and run "selected cells". By this, the formulas of selected cells are removed and the values are left.
- When you test "all data cells" is run from the custom menu, please run "selected cells". By this, the formulas of all data cells in the active sheet are removed and the values are left.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)